How to create users with different types of fields in django?
how to create models for different types of users with different types of fields in django?
Suppose I have 2 users: doctors and nurses, and doctors have a doctor_id, and dept, apart from the fields common between nurses and doctors.How to proceed then?
Searched everywhere and scratched my head, can anyone let me know how to approach this?
I have tried to write something like this, but it doesnt work.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'doctor'),
        (2, 'nurse'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

class DoctorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    doctor_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class NurseProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    nurse_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



If I understand correctly, you want to have two models.
If you want to add an abstraction layer, you can do that:
class User(AbstractUser):
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class NurseProfile(User):
    user_type = (2, 'nurse')

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class DoctorProfile(User):
    user_type = (1, 'doctor')
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=255)

The previous example used a proxy for Nurse, because you can keep the clear Nurse/Doctor logic and abstract-User-layer as a table in the db. In my opinion you dont need user_type at all, but i keep it in example.
If you don't need an additional user, you can use simple inheritance:
class NurseProfile(AbstraxctUser):
    user_type = (2, 'nurse')
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class DoctorProfile(NurseProfile):
    user_type = (1, 'doctor')
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=255)

Of course, you get a new question about how to get the doctor and nurse together from database.

?: (models.E017) Proxy model 'NurseProfile' contains model fields.
?: (models.E017) Proxy model 'DoctorProfile' contains model fields.                I am getting these errors now

please provide me your code. in my example i dont mark DoctorProfile as proxy model.

A common method is to define your own Profile object with a OneToOne link to a User:
class Profile( models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey( User, ...
    # and any other fields you want

Documentation here
Profiles contain a set of common fields. You could have a choicefield that is Doctor or Nurse, and a doctor_id field which is null (or zero or blank) for a nurse.
Then you can refer to (for example) self.request.user.profile.fieldname
Note that until you are certain that a profile for the user exists, your program will throw aNotFound error when you do this. A simple fix is to create a blank profile in your post-login view if hasattr( user, 'profile) is False. Or in your create-user context, if this information is not user-editable.
